# In AnyLogic v7, how can I change an agent's place in a process flow through java?

Tags: java, anylogic

In AnyLogic v7, I would like to use an event to reset all of my agents to a certain place in the process flow at the beginning of each work day.  I have the event created and have a loop which can loop through all of the agents, but I'm not sure what property or method I need to actually relocate the agent to a particular delay block.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Put an `Enter` block and connect it with the block that reflects "a certain place".
2. At agent canvas, call code like: `main.enter.take(currenBlock().remove(this));`

`currentBlock().remove(this)` removes the agent itself from his current flowchart block and returns it. `enter.take(...)` injects agent in flowchart, `Enter` block instantly forwards agent to the next block. It works like `Source` block, but here it injects already existing agent, while `Source` creates new agent. main. is reference to top-level agent that contains flowchart.

Comment: You also need to worry about any side-effects of moving the Agents; e.g., if the original place they were in triggered some other behaviour in the model, that might need to be 'cancelled' in some way. In a pure DES (process-modelling) model this is normally not an issue.